# SQL Lead/Lag until a certain condition and update the previous/next rows with a value from the row that hits the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a dataset as below:

```
Customer    Document    Date        Date Cleared
151         Invoice     18.02.2019  null
151         Receipt     14.02.2019  14.02.2019
151         Invoice     18.01.2019  null
151         Invoice     18.12.2018  null
151         Invoice     19.11.2018  null
152         Receipt     7.11.2018   7.11.2018
152         Invoice     18.10.2018  null
152         Invoice     18.09.2018  null
152         Receipt     26.09.2018  26.09.2018
152         Invoice     20.08.2018  null
```

This is just an example with 2 customers. I want to find out when the invoices are paid according to the closest receipt (since they are ordered by date).

What I want to accomplish is to update the invoices with the date of the previous receipt for each customer.

Expected output:

```
Customer    Document    Date        Date Cleared
151         Invoice     18.02.2019  null
151         Receipt     14.02.2019  14.02.2019
151         Invoice     18.01.2019  14.02.2019
151         Invoice     18.12.2018  14.02.2019
151         Invoice     19.11.2018  14.02.2019
152         Receipt     7.11.2018   7.11.2018
152         Invoice     18.10.2018  7.11.2018
152         Invoice     18.09.2018  7.11.2018
152         Receipt     26.09.2018  26.09.2018
152         Invoice     20.08.2018  26.09.2018
```

I thought this would be pretty easy with a simple lag/lead function however there might more than 1 invoice before a receipt so it has to lag until the document column is receipt. Also the first line for each customer can be an invoice or a receipt as in this example. If the invoice is the first line, we assume it is not paid (cleared) yet.

The solution might not even involve lag or lead functions, this is just my initial thought.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Customer INT,
    Document VARCHAR(100),
    Date DATE,
    DateCleared DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
(151, 'Invoice', '20190218', NULL),
(151, 'Receipt', '20190214', '20190214'),
(151, 'Invoice', '20190118', NULL),
(151, 'Invoice', '20181218', NULL),
(151, 'Invoice', '20181119', NULL),
(152, 'Receipt', '20181107', '20181107'),
(152, 'Invoice', '20181018', NULL),
(152, 'Invoice', '20180918', NULL),
(152, 'Receipt', '20180926', '20180926'),
(152, 'Invoice', '20180820', NULL)

UPDATE invoice
SET DateCleared = matchingReceipt.DateCleared
FROM @Table AS invoice CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) receipt.DateCleared
        FROM @Table AS receipt
        WHERE invoice.Customer = receipt.Customer AND
            invoice.Date < receipt.Date AND
            receipt.Document = 'Receipt'
        ORDER BY DateCleared ASC
    ) AS matchingReceipt
WHERE invoice.Document = 'Invoice'

SELECT * FROM @Table ORDER BY Customer, Date
```

I added an identity column to the table. You use a CROSS APPLY where you search for the matching receipt given your rules (same customer, cleared after the invoice and more recent).

Comment: @nitu This is a great answer thank you. Just one more question, say I have another column named STATUS with values of open or closed. For invoices that are open, I don't want to add the cleared date to the DateCleared column and instead just keep them null. How would I establish this condition as well?

Comment: You welcome. Regarding your comment, after "WHERE invoice.Document = 'Invoice'", add "AND STATUS = 'Closed'" (by the way, it's better to use equality then inequality ie STATUS = 'Closed' than STATUS <> 'Open').

Comment: @nitu thanks a lot. I just noticed 2 small problems: 1) some of the invoices can already be cleared even if they are the last entry because customer overpaid in the previous months. So if the status = 'closed' it should pick up the DateCleared of the previous receipt. 2) If say the last 3 entries of a customer are invoices then only the 3rd one receives the DateCleared and the last 2 entries are still null. Again if their status are closed then the last 2 entries in this example should also get the same DateCleared value of the 3rd entry.  How can I solve these 2 problems?